# Not connecting to Internet in windows 10 1909

Tags: networking, windows-10

Recently I have uninstalled my outdated escan antivirus after that I can't connect to internet. Wifi is connecting and showing internet access but my laptop is not getting the internet not by any browser and not for even windows update.

In browsers showing DNS_probe_finished_nxdomain.

I have tried troubleshooting, DNS flushing , updated the network drive,  restarting system, restarting DNS, used another dns,power off the system , using tethering but no use, wifi is connecting with other systems without any problems.​​​​

Somehow now internet explorer and TeamViewer can connect to internet now.

My laptop is hp pavilion 15-cs1052tx.windows 10 1909.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this problem. When I uninstalled the antivirus some files got corrupted. My windows 10 version was 1909 , so I used windows 10 update assistant to upgrade to 20H2.At first it doesn't connect to internet ,I tried to connect it again, on the second try it worked . Successfully upgrade to 20H2 and all the problems also resolved.